# Vertical UIScrollView without code behind

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

My goal is to have `background image` that fills whole screen and above that image there will be vertical scroll view because labels and text inputs will be stacked vertically, somehow i managed to achieve this, but after i added `Navigation Controller`, layout got messed up.

I simulated the `View Controller` size to height of `1000` so i can constraint the labels and inputs correctly, but how would i handle the image size and scroll sizes?

[image]

Comment: If you're using autolayout just set the width and height by control dragging on the scroll view

Comment: Yes, pretty much after i set Space constraints to controls I needed to set Equal Widths contraint to all controls with the Scroll View control